# Are open intervals or union of open intervals the only two possible elements in any basis of usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

Can $\mathbb{R}$ ususal topology has a basis which contains elements other than open interval?

Answer (score 3):

Certainly. E.g. the basis consisting of all open sets, or of all sets that are the union of two disjoint intervals, or of all sets that are the union of countably many disjoint open intervals.

Comment: right, and for some of these examples the bass contains no open intervals at all

Comment: @Mirko is there a base for usual topology on R contains no open intervals at all?

Comment: @Cathy David gave the example of unions of two disjoint open intervals.  None of these is an interval.

Comment: @saulspatz I see. Thanks, but unions of two disjoint open intervals can still be somewhat decomposed into intervals, I mean is it possible for a base of R usual has elements other than intervals or union of intervals?

Comment: @Cathy Every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a union of open intervals, so it's not possible.

Comment: No, that is not possible. The fact that open intervals **are** a basis implies that *every* open set can be written as a union of sets each of which is an open interval. Similarly, the fact that unions of two disjoint open intervals form a basis means that *every* open set can be written as a union of sets each of which is a union of two disjoint open intervals

Answer (score 0):

A basis for the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is a collection of open sets which (1) covers $\mathbb{R}$, and (2) is such that given any two elements $B_1,B_2$ in the basis and a point $x_0\in B_1\cap B_2$ we can find a set $B$ in the basis such that $x_0\in B\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$.

So the slightly more interesting question in the OP's comments was: can we find a basis which does not contain **any** open intervals at all? Answer: yes.

Take the collection $\{B\cup B': B,B'\text{ are disjoint nonempty open intervals}\}$. It is easy to see that it satisfies the conditions.

To make it slightly more interesting, we can find a **countable** basis of this type. Eg let $I_{n,r}=(r-3/n,r+1/n)\cup(r+2/n,r+3/n)$ and take the collection of all $I_{n,r}$ where $r$ is rational and $n$ is a positive integer.

Note that $(r-1/n,r+1/n)\subset I_{n,r}$. The $I_{n,r}$ are obviously open sets and obviously cover $\mathbb{R}$. So if we take $x_0\in I_{n,r}\cap I_{n',r'}$ then some interval $(x-2/m,x+2/m)\subset I_{n,r}\cap I_{n',r'}$. We pick any rational $s$ in the interval $(x-1/m,x+1/m)$ and $I_{m,s}\subset (x-2/m,x+2/m)\subset I_{n,r}\cap I_{n',r'}$